# Почему в TXT файле отступы не появляются?

Tags: c#

Вот код:

```
string firstA = "CREATE DATABASE " + textBox1.Text + ";" + "\n";
string firstB = "USE " + textBox1.Text + ";" + "\n";
firstPart = firstA + firstB;

secondPart = "CREATE TABLE " + textBox2.Text + ";" + "\n";

System.IO.StreamWriter textFile = new System.IO.StreamWriter(@"E:\" + path + ".txt");
textFile.WriteLine(firstPart + secondPart);
textFile.Close();
```

Выводит:

```
CREATE DATABASE data;USE data;CREATE TABLEusers;
```

А должно:

```
CREATE DATABASE data;
USE data;
CREATE TABLE users;
```

В чем причина? Ведь кажется все правильно =/

Comment: Кто выводит? Чем смотрели файл `E:\????.txt`?

Comment: Environment.NewLine

Comment: @alexlz через блокнот :/

Comment: @navu1893 Странно он работает. Я бы не удивился, если бы файл выглядел вот так:

     CREATE DATABASE data;
                          USE data;
                                   CREATE TABLE users;

А в одну строчку -- сильно странная программа блокнот.

Answer (score 3):

Не заморачивайтесь с системными концами строк. Пусть за вас работает техника:

```
var commands = new[]
{
    string.Format("CREATE DATABASE {0};", textBox1.Text),
    string.Format("USE {0};", textBox1.Text),
    string.Format("CREATE TABLE {0};", textBox2.Text)
};

File.WriteAllLines(@"E:\" + path + ".txt", commands);
```

---

Кстати, подумайте, что будет, если пользователь в `textBox1` введёт `DB`, а в `textBox2`

> TEST; DROP DATABASE DB; COMMIT

(и почитайте про SQL injection и prepared statements).

Comment: Можно вопрос? Как можно сделать так: у меня есть кнопка, при нажатии в C# создать БД. Как бы создать интерпретатор? Т.е вместо набора текста он работает в визуальной среде и в конце создается БД. Надеюсь донес свою мысль

Comment: @navi1893: Не совсем понятно. Интерпретатор чего? Если вы имеете в виду программу, составляющую SQL-команды по вводу пользователя и общающуюся в базой данных, то в общем вы идёте правильным путём, но я бы (1) разделил интерфейс и рабочую часть на отдельные модули, (2) не генерировал текст в файл, а работал с базой напрямую через напр. Entity Framework.

Comment: @VladD "не генерировал текст в файл, а работал с базой напрямую через напр." вот мне это интересно. Как могу сделать? Можете подсказать?

Comment: @navi1893: [Entity Framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/ef.aspx) же! Ну и куча других способов есть.

Answer (score 2):

В конце строк надо `"\r\n"` вместо `"\n"`.

Comment: И что даст? Переводы-то строк должны быть.

Comment: сработало! Спасибо

Answer (score 1):

В .Net есть класс System.Enviroment, а у него есть строковое свойство NewLine. Пример использования:

```
string firstA = "CREATE DATABASE " + textBox1.Text + ";" + Enviroment.NewLine;
```

а вообще склеивание большого количества строк через "+" - это моветон. Лучше использовать string.Format(...) или класс StringBuilder. Например:

```
string firstA = string.Format("CREATE DATABASE {0};{1}", textBox1.Text, Enviroment.NewLine);

string firstA = new StringBuilder().Append("CREATE DATABASE ").Append(textBox1.Text).AppendLine(";");
```